# jQuery .load remote content into div, keep scope for links etc

Tags: jquery

if I load a file contents into a div using:

```
$("testDiv").load('http://outserver/Siteb/search');
```

I get the search page in the div. The page in question has a search form. I want the resulting page to be bound within the same div, rather than take over as normal.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use iframe or post search request with jquery and add search results into the same div

Comment: @Marek Sebera thanks, can you post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IFRAME to do this:

```
<iframe src="http://outserver/Siteb/search" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Or Create whole View logic by jQuery

1) $("#testDiv").load('http://outserver/Siteb/search');
2) $("form").submit() //handle form submit and submit it via AJAX call
3) get results through AJAX
4) display results in div, without need to refresh page

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use load to do this because, as the documentation state,

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   the same origin policy; the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol

If you want to do that on the same domain, you should definitly load it into an iframe as Marek suggested

Comment: I have used load to do this. You're assuming that the site containing testDiv is on another server, for the purposes of the example the site with the div is outserver/Sitea loading outserver/Siteb/search. That part works fine.

Comment: Then as marek said, use an iframe